# Angular cdkDrag elements move away from cursor when tried to drag?

Tags: html, angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am creating a chatbot which is draggable. I have a parent div which has Angular's cdkDrag applied, under that div I have 2 elements chat-icon and window. When I double click the icon to drag it moves away from the cursor but the same works properly when done again. I am completely new to this please help.

I don't know what to try but here is example of my code:-

```
<div cdkDrag
    <div class="chat-icon" </div> //when clicked will open chat-window
    <div class="chat-window" 
        ...Code for Chatbot
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.